# Find all permissions associated with a local group

Tags: windows, windows-xp, permissions, user-accounts

I'm migrating a Windows machine to some new hardware.  I have the new machine built and everything installed, but there's one thing that's not working.  I've narrowed it down to a local security group on the old machine that doesn't exist on the new machine.  I can create the group, of course, but I need to know what permissions to associate with the group.

So how can I get a list out of Windows XP Pro of every permission associated with a particular group?

A little more detail:
This machine is a member of a domain, but it has a specific purpose — running an application used by our library's circulation desk.  There's a service that runs as a specific user, and individual users log in to the machine (work study students and library administrators).  I have created the group and added the appropriate accounts, and I can make the application work if I then make the group itself a member of the local administrators group.  However, that's not a real solution for our work study accounts.  I need to recreate the security used by the prior machine.

Comment: Is the software vendor or developer who created the application not available to tell you the required permissions?  Documentation?  Beyond that, I'd look for a utility which tells you which permissions are being requested by a process.  Saw one about 8 years ago, have not needed it since.  I'll look around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AccessChk from SysInternals claims to produce the list of privileges a given user or group is granted.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx

After more thought, I decided that by modifying the audit policy on the machine, you can cause log entries to be created when a process is used.  in GPEDIT.MSC (or the AD equivalent), Computer Config -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Audit Policy.  Start by enabling audit of both Success/Failure of Object Access (for files/folders etc), Directory Access, Privilege Use, and Process Tracking.  Or perhaps just check DENY to more quickly show you what's missing.